# Securing Entities with Claims Based Authorization in Web Api 2 OData Endpoint

Tags: entity-framework, claims-based-identity, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-authorization

Given the following Controller

```
namespace MyNamespace.Api.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class AccountController : ODataController
    {
        private Entities db = new Entities();

        // GET odata/Account
        [Queryable]
        [ClaimsPrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Operation = "Read", Resource = "Account")]
        public IQueryable<Account> GetAccount()
        {
            return db.Accounts();
        }

        ...

    }

}
```

I override the `ClaimsAuthorizationManager.CheckAccess(...)`

```
public class AuthorizationManager : ClaimsAuthorizationManager
{
    public override bool CheckAccess(AuthorizationContext context)
    {
        var resource = context.Resource.First().Value;
        var action = context.Action.First().Value;

        return Policies.Validate(resource, action);
    }
}
```

This is useful only to the point where I can check whether or not the `Current Principal` **in general** can `Read` `Account`. However, if I'd want to check which accounts a certain user is allowed to Read, I am lost.

Let's say I have a Manager user who should be able to read all Accounts for which he is a manager for whereas a non-manager user should be able to read only their own account.

Is there a best practice for this or have you done something like this previously and give me a few hints to look for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not use `ClaimsPrincipalPermissionAttribute` because I cannot pass any dynamic parameters to it like requested Account from your sample.

Have a look at the book "Pro APS.NET Web API Security" page 97. They suggest to invoke AuthorizationManager from your controller action implementation by code `new IdentityConfiguration().ClaimsAuthorizationManager.CheckAccess(context)`, where `context` is constructed manually so you can pass `Account` requested (for example) as `Resource` to check it in your `AuthorizationManager` implementation.

Also have a look at pluralsight training "Introduction to Identity and Access Control in .NET 4.5". There are also some info about how to implement claim-based security in Web API.

Now I am in progress of implementing the security you are talking about and I am interesting in the subject too.

My case is: role Administrator is assigned by Country, every Administrator can see entities only related to the countries they have access to.

UPDATE: After several projects I forgot about Claims-based security as this is extremely difficult way to make security checks. Today I use decorator pattern where all the security checks are done. It appears to be very easy to implement security even in OData Controllers like this: 
`public IQueriable MyQuriableEntitySet
{
    get{ return implementationWithoutSecurity.MyQuriableEntitySet.Where(e=>e.Country.Code = currentUser.AssignedTo.CountryCode || currentUser.IsSuperAdmin); }
}`

Comment: Great :) More reading. They say the print industry is dying but I beg to disagree. Of course there's Kindle but I prefer printed copies.